# How to inlude pseudonym field in ssl certificate using openssl cli?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, csr

I am trying to include `pseudonym` in the SSL certificate from `openssl` cli. I have created `csr` using command `openssl req -new -nodes -config openssl_test.cnf -outform PEM -out test.csr`. The content of `openssl_test.cnf` is

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default            # The default ca section
.
.

policy          = policy_anything

[ policy_anything ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional
pseudonym               = supplied

[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
0.CN=sample
1.O=test1
2.OU=test1-1
3.pseudonym=00000001111112222222
```

The `pseudonym` is included in `csr` (verfied using `openssl req -in test.csr -noout -text` command). But when I sign the `csr` using `openssl ca` the `pseudonym` is ignored in the end certificate.

```
openssl ca -config openssl_ca.cnf -out test.crt -infiles test.csr
```

But when I check the certificate contents (`openssl x509 -text -noout -in test.crt`) I don't see `pseudonym` field. Also tried with `prompt = yes` option in `openssl_test.cnf` and passed values from cli but it's same issue.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

P.S: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, Ubuntu 20.04. Please let me know if any info is missing.

Comment: Not programming or development, but: you show the policy in `openssl_test.cnf` but you run the `ca` command with `-config openssl_ca.cnf` -- is the policy present and correct in THAT file?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, you are right. `pseudonym = supplied` was missing in `openssl_ca.cnf` file. Thanks for the hint.